# Can I use PUT http method to retrieve the data instead of using GET

Tags: rest, http

Is it possible to design this way.
Can put method retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP does not stop you from doing so, but why would you?

Comment: It was an interview question

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question. Yes you can.

Any of of GET,POST,PUT,DELETE methods can return a Representation (Response Object)
No framework will stop you (Most).

Should I do that?

Well, These HTTP verbs are there for a reason. In other words, they describe what they do.

In case of PUT:

`Client sends Representation to update existing one. Server returns either 200    with empty body / 200 with newly updated representation`

Just to add, If you don't want `GET` to do what you trying to do, Use `POST` with some sensible URL

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately not,
officially the REST methods are

```
POST -> Create a new resource
GET ->  (Read) Gets an existing resource
PUT  ->  Updates a resource or changes its status
DELETE ->  Deletes a resource
```

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Comment: There is no such thing as "REST methods". "Rest" is an architectural style, and you apply these principles to HTTP. But that was not the question here.